# Ruby concat strings with UTF-8 characters results in strange ordering

Tags: ruby, internationalization

```
1.9.3-p194 :059 >   arabic
 => "أَبْجَدِيَّة عَ" 

1.9.3-p194 :065 > arabic.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8> 


1.9.3-p194 :068 > "begin #{arabic} end " + " Goodbye "
=> "begin أَبْجَدِيَّة عَ end  Goodbye " 

1.9.3-p194 :067 > "#{arabic} end " + " Goodbye "
=> "end  Goodbye أَبْجَدِيَّة عَ"
```

I want the last output to read " أَبْجَدِيَّة عَ end  Goodbye ".

What character encoding hoops do I have to go through to get ruby to ignore that the arabic is a RTL language?

---

**UPDATE**:

I was able to reproduce this in the following rubies:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
jruby 1.7.3 (1.9.3p385) 2013-02-21 dac429b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_15-b03 [linux-amd64]
jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-06-07 fffffff on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_15-b03 [linux-amd64]
```

[Here is a gist with the code from above](https://gist.github.com/olore/5731268)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been fixed. Ruby has no idea that Arabic is a RTL language. Can't replicate it on either 2.0.0-p0, 1.9.3-p392, or any other Ruby I have installed. Try upgrading to a recent version of 1.9.

Comment: can you try again using the gist I posted? I don't see it working in anything i tried? thx

Comment: @olore: Same result. What is your system language? If your system language is a RTL language, that might explain the behavior, as mine is English.

Comment: My locale is set to 'en_US.UTF-8'. I'm on Centos6.4. Appreciate the help

Comment: @olore: I havn't given much ;). This probably isn't a Linux issue, as I'm on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution could be to use [Left-to-right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) mark, here is html example:

```
"#{arabic_str1}"+" &lrm;"+"#{arabic_str2}"
```

Works well for me (1.9.3p392 ruby version).